# output of a collection using powershell and htmlAgilityPack

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, html-agility-pack

First, yes I am a noob to scripting and powershell as that will become painfully obvious.  In my attempts to learn, I have been working with a script from here: http://www.leeholmes.com/blog/2010/03/05/html-agility-pack-rocks-your-screen-scraping-world/

This is what I have thus far:

```
add-type -Path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\htmlAgilityPack\HtmlAgilityPack.dll'
$doc = New-Object HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument 
$result = $doc.Load("C:\scipts\test.html") 
$texts = $doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table[@class='dataTable']/tbody/tr/td[1]/a[1]") 
$result = $texts | % {
$testText = $_
$Platform = $testtext.innertext
New-Object PsObject -Property @{ Platform = $Platform} | Select Platform 
}
$result | Sort Platform | out-string
```

This gives me the items I am looking for.

*** The Challenge ***

I am trying to get that output into a variable as a single string with each item followed by a comma. for Example Item1, Item2, Item 3 etc...

Any help or explanation would be appreciated as I have Googled myself cross-eyed and don't necessarily stand the things I am finding.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know if there is any builtin operators for PowerShell to do this but [`String.Join()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.join.aspx).

Comment: I did try powershell variations of -split and -join with out any success

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the powershell help (`get-help about_join`):

> The following diagram shows the syntax for the join operator.

```
<String[]> -Join <Delimiter>
```

To solve your problem, you need to:

1. Create an array of strings containing the strings you want to join:

   ```
   $arrayofstrings = $result | Sort Platform | foreach-object {$_.Platform}
   ```
2. Join the strings using a comma as the delimiter:

   ```
   $joinedstring = $arrayofstrings -join ", "
   ```

`$joinedstring`will contain `Item1, Item2, Item3`

Comment: I'd probably use `$result | select -exp Platform | sort`.

Comment: That worked!  Thanks so much Jon.  I had previously tried -join, I just wasn't using it correctly or in the right place.